# Mapped ports + macvlan woes

Tags: docker, docker-network

I need a containerto have ports on the host available so it can always be connected to on the same hostname, but also a secondary network connection that gives the container its own LAN IP (via macvlan).

Is that technically possible with both of those on 1 network interface?

The main interface for the machine is fbond0, the macvlan network was created on top of that interface:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet 10.123.56.0/22 --ip-range=10.123.59.64/27 -o macvlan_mode=bridge -o parent=bond25g macvlan214
```

When the container starts normally with port mappings, it works as expected:

```
PORTS                                                              
0.0.0.0:49215->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49216->5000/tcp
```

As soon as it's connected to the 2nd network:

```
PORTS
22/tcp, 5000/tcp
```

After disconnect, we get new mappings:

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:49217->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49218->5000/tcp
```

We already use this setup on a different server, but since that one is outside of the relevant VLAN, a (VLAN'ed) network interface was added, so the exposed ports are not on the same interface as the macvlan functionality far as the OS is concerned.

I'm assuming we'll probably need a similar solution here? Add a 2nd virtual network interface so we can separate things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future me and anyone else experiencing this problem, apparently it has to do with how `libnetwork` chooses a default gateway. Normally this would be based on the interface priority, but given that you cannot change the priority from the configuration, they decided on "[choosing the first network in alphabetically order](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21741)".

Basically, because my macvlan came earlier alphabetically sorted, it was chosen as the default network. Because a macvlan is a lot like host networking, it does not support port mapping. Hence the ports were removed.